# #define line of code to something else

Tags: c++, c

Is it at all possible in c/c++ to do something like to following:

```
#define (_asm int 3;) (exit(1))
```

So that everywhere in my code this line will be replaced at compile time.
I know this is bad practice but is it possible.

cheers

Comment: `#define _asm exit` `#define int (1)` `#define 3` et voila!

Comment: Ask yourself what you want to achieve. If you need to switch between `_asm int 3;`and `exit(1)`, then do as Paul R recommends - and then I woudln't call it bad practice. --- OK, just seeing you already got it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do a global search and replace with your programming editor (or IDE) of choice and change `_asm int 3` to e.g. `FOO`, and then define a macro `FOO` like this:

```
#if 1 // <<<- change this test to determine how `FOO` is expanded
  #define FOO _asm int 3
#else
  #define FOO exit(1)
#endif
```

Comment: This I like very much. I guess I was just trying to be too lazy, doing it in a single line.

Comment: OK - just make sure you use a more meaningful/unique name than `FOO` though. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not a valid preprocessor symbol so it won't work.

You can probably do this replacement easily enough by using external tools (or just any editor's search and replace functionality), of course.